# Transparent vectortiles

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, vector-tiles

**Background**

I am playing around with mapbox and uploaded a shapefile from which I created a vector tileset. I loaded the tileset into mapxbox studio to create a custom style. My aim is to solely display the vector tileset with no background layer at all. I am doing this for the reason because I want to overlay the tileset over another  raster tileset via leaflet later on. In mapbox studio this looks as follows - you can see the colored vectors and  the surrounding transparent area:

[image]

**Problem:**

When I try to visualize both tilesets via leaflet, I am not able to see through the first tileset. Instead I am seeing my colored vector with a black background:
[image]

Any chance I can make the tileset background transparent? So the vectors wont be surrounded by a black background anymore but rather by the underlying raster tile set?

**Here some code snippets I am using:**

```
<div id='map'>
</div>

<script>
  var sat  = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/xxx/xxx/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=xxx', {
    attribution: 'Raster tile set'
});


var clc = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/xxx/xxx/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=xxx', {
    attribution: 'Transparent vector tile set'
});

 var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [48.2, 16.37],
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [sat, clc]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the image format for the tiles you're requesting, jpg or png? Also, have you read https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps ?

Comment: @maRtin I do have the same problem as you have: in MapBox studio, I have a tileset which has a transparent background. When using in Leaflet the background is black. Did you find a solution? I figured out that using a different url with the id of the tileselt sort of works but gives a lot of 404 errors: `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/TILESET_ID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: I also have the issue using leaflet and gdal2tiles generated tiles.   I will look for a code snippet it leaflet.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now...